# Replace every comma in a column with a dot

Tags: sql

Could someone tell me a query to replace every comma from a column 'myColumn' with a dot, without messing up with the numbers?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would use an update statement:

```
update t
    set myColumn = replace(myColumn, ',', '.')
    where myColumn like '%,%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Pruebe con:

UPDATE prices SET pvp = REPLACE(pvp, ',', '.');