# PHP Remove " from string

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a PHP Script that fetches text from the database, and what I want to do is the following:

If the text from the database looks like this:

```
[url="something"]Some text[/url]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[url=something]Some text[/url]
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you want to change the text _within_ the database to remove the quote, you should take a gander at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7734956/899126) answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace('"','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '[url="something"]Some text[/url]';
echo $text = preg_replace('#\[url="(.*?)"\]#i','[url=$1]', $text);
```