# sql calls do weird things with this character : "

Tags: php, sql

I have a form that auto calls information for products, it uses autocomplete to pull the product description when someone puts in the product name.  When the form calls the data, sample data may look like this :

Samsung 40" HDTV Television

After the form is saved, and reloaded, the data loaded looks like this :

Samsung 40

Is there a way to mass edit my product descriptions to replace " with inch, or to make this not happen

Using SQL

Code sample of insert :

```
foreach (blabla)
$productName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $invoice_detail['productName'] ) );
$query = "INSERT INTO invoice (`productName`) VALUES ('$productName')
mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
```

Code sample of retrieve :

```
<td><input value="<?php echo isset($item['productName']) ? $item['productName']: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][productName]" id="itemName_<?php echo $key+1?>"></td>
```

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Can you show us the code that insert this? and the code that displays it.

Comment: @Halcyon sure, please give me a moment and I will update my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Replace Character in Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns)

Comment: While I think this is a duplicate, I think a better solution is to better escape your strings so that you can support double quotes.

Comment: @JNevill as you can see from the code OP posted, the MySQL arguments are already being escaped. The problem is in displaying the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not escaping html special symbols, your code:

```
echo isset($item['productName']) ? $item['productName']: '';
```

should look like this:

```
echo isset($item['productName']) ? htmlspecialchars($item['productName']) : '';
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!  This worked perfectly, and saved a lot of sql headaches.  Are there any other special escapes that are worthy knowing such as this one?

Comment: there are 2 main problems: sql injections and html injections, for first one you're already using `mysqli_real_escape_string` for second one `htmlspecialchars`, of course there are also javascript/csv/xml - but they are quite rare

Comment: So I have like 4 different fields for the product line, should I be using htmlspecialchars for each of them then?

Comment: @Steven yes, every piece of data which goes to html should be properly escaped, I'm usually testing this by inserting `<script>alert('');</script>` into every text field

Comment: thats genius!  so if its escaped, the code will not run, but if it is not, you get a notification - Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Steven right, you can insert this via simple sql script on dev/test server and then it much easier to see those errors