# how to convert any char to - in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have one column in sql table like this

```
    codel
-------------
124/500/319/1
500/2698794/3
130.500.2804508.1
800/283478/2
155-305-340007-1
130.500.2686821.1
```

how i can convert this code to

```
     codel
-------------
124-500-319-1
500-2698794-3
130-500-2804508-1
800-283478-2
155-305-340007-1
130-500-2686821-1
```

thank you for read my qustion

Comment: You can check this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4):

In `SQL Server 2017`, you can also do it using `TRANSLATE` like following.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(codel,'/.','--') AS Codel FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: This would be my recommendation. Should work in sqlazure too.

Comment: Side trivia; been available in oracle for about 20 years! Oracle's one is slightly more useful too in that the replace pattern can be shorter and any find pattern letter that has no mapping is replaced with an empty string. Very handy. In sqls you have to translate to a common character then REPLACE it with empty string

Answer (score 2):

Try below - using `replace()` function

```
select replace(replace(codel,'/','-'),'.','-') from tablename
```

Comment: And this is what you need to do in versions below sqls 2017

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using replace

```
   SELECT REPLACE(codel, '/', '-'); 
    go
  SELECT REPLACE(codel, '.', '-');
```